# LLVM/Clang: Reducing a compound statement to a subset

Tags: c++, llvm-clang, llvm-c++-api

I have a compound statement representing the following block of code

```
    {
      int a = 3;
      foo(a);
      a = 4;
      foo(a);
      a = 5;
    }
```

I want to create another compound statement which contains the first 2 statements of the original one and looks like this:

```
    {
      int a = 3;
      foo(a);
    }
```

And then another one containing the following 2 statements:

```
    {
      a = 4;
      foo(a);
    }
```

I have the call to `foo(a)` as `clang::CallExpr`.

The only idea I have so far is too iterate over the original compound statement and fill the other compound statement until `foo(a)` is found. But the API doesn't seem to have a possibility to compare statements.
Any better ideas?

Comment: I'm sure you mean `int a = 4;` as the first statement in the second compound statement?

Comment: @5gon12eder I don't know yet if I care. Maybe I will. For now, I just want to split that compound statement.